# C# simple exception output

Tags: c#, security, exception

I am making a program of which needs to output any errors that occur but in a timely fashion, it is a program for password recovery.

How can I change the exception text variable which is probably a string to only the actual exception minus all the unneeded stuff.

```
 catch(Exception EX)
 {
     Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
     Console.WriteLine("AN ERROR OCCURED IN COPYING CHROMEPASSFILE: " + EX);
     Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
 }
```

Output:

```
AN ERROR OCCURED IN COPYING CHROMEPASSFILE: System.IO.IOException: The file 'C:\Users\Anonymous\Desktop\E_TEST\logindata.' already exists.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
at Recover_All_Passwords.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Anonymous\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Recover_All_Passwords\Recover_All_Passwords\Program.cs:line 27
```

How can I output only that first line and none of those "At(s)"?

Just noticed the tag for exception says, I quote "An exception is a **rarely occurring** (exceptional!) condition that requires deviation from the program's normal flow."

**Edit**

Yes, the stacktrace is very helpful however I had only require the error message because the user will not be interested in anything but what had actually failed.

Comment: Replace `Console.WriteLine("AN ERROR OCCURED IN COPYING CHROMEPASSFILE: " + EX);
` with `Console.WriteLine("AN ERROR OCCURED IN COPYING CHROMEPASSFILE: " + EX.Message);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using `EX`, use the `Message` property on the Exception.

So your code becomes:

```
 Console.WriteLine("AN ERROR OCCURED IN COPYING CHROMEPASSFILE: " + EX.Message);
```

For future reference, the "at(s)" are the [StackTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx) and are **extremely** useful for determining where your application is breaking..

Comment: Thank you, that works. I realize that the at(s) are useful however this is a "quick deploy" utility. I may have the program create a txt file in the same location that has advanced statistics of the program after running